# Work Item Customization - Rule behavior in Transition and State

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

**Simple use case**: in a work item workflow, a field must be REQUIRED in TRANSITION="Active to Resolved" and READONLY when in State="Resolved".

**Customization**: For that field, I have set the rule REQUIRED in the Transition details, and the Rule READONLY in the State details.

**Behavior**: When I change the work item State from Active to Resolved (without saving) the field becomes REQUIRED and READONLY. I was expecting that field switched to READONLY only after saving the work item to Resolved and not during transition.

**Question**: WHY the rule READONLY is applied in the Transition? Is this the common behavior of the workflows?

---

I'm working on TFS 2010. To edit the work item template I'm using Team Explroer Power tools (Process Editor). Work Item behavior is tested from Team Explorer e team Web access.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of TFS?  And which UI are you using to edit the WI's (Web, VS)?

Comment: @Dylan I've extended the question with the information you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `READONLY` condition *should* have been evaluated only after saving but it won't. However you can wrap it within a [`WHENNOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) condition (albeit not ideal solution as your filed must be filled before the state transition). e.g.:

```
<STATE value="Resolved">
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="Your.Field">
      <WHENNOT field="Your.Field" value="">
        <READONLY />
      </WHENNOT>
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</STATE>
```